# "Work offline" button functionality command in Windows

Tags: windows, offline-files

Windows has the "Offline Files" and sometimes (actually, most of the time) Windows does not recognize when the connection is back and I want to manually disable "Work Offline" mode with this button in the explorer:

[image]

Is there a command (e.g., with rundll etc) which I can use to automate this?

Comment: *Windows does not recognize when the connection is back and I have to manually disable "Work Offline" mode.* - If I am not mistaken, this is intended behavior. In any case, please consider editing your question and expanding on 1) the conditions you would want the connection reestablished and 2) whether there are any restrictions on the approaches to be taken (such as whether or not third-party, non-MS utilities or scripting is a viable option).

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Isn't my question crisp clear? "Is there a command (e.g., with rundll etc) which I can use to automate this?" (and title is similar). It is not about the offline functionality, it is how to execute the command behing this button (e.g. using a shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a command (e.g., with rundll etc) which I can use to automate this?

The strict answer to your question appears to be no. There is no single command that you can use to affect this setting (as far as I am aware). You will likely need to use a PowerShell script (or similar) if you want to automate this feature.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a "single" command. A PowerShell script is of course an appropriate way to automate this (but if so, how?). I am happy even with an API call that I can call from a simple C program or similar.